# how to find the LCM of a set of numbers any length

Tags: c#, math

im doing a thing, i need to find the LCM of the set of numbers all at indexes of [n, 1] in a long 2d array,

```
        static long LCM(long a, long b) => (a * b) / GCD(a, b);
        static long GCD(long a, long b) => b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
        public static void convertFrac(long[,] lst)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            long lcm = lst[0, 1];
            for(int i = 1; i < lst.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                lcm = LCM(lcm, lst[i, 1]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(lcm);
        }
```

right now if i put in { { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 1, 4 } } i get 6 instead of 12

Answer (score 0):

It's just because your ending point of the for statement is wrong. It's not < but <= that would work until the end of your array (or let the < sign and add 1 to the upper limit but that would be... odd, wouldn't it?)

By the way, if you just moved your Console.Writeline inside the loop, you'll have it figured very fast.